# Checking for mobile browser in the angular run block rather than in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that I use to detect for mobile browsers, and I currently add it to a directive. However, I typically need to check for mobile browsers in multiple spots in my app, and I was wondering whether it would make more sense to do the check in the run block of my angular app, and then store it using the a value so it is available across the app?

```
angular.module('app')
  .directive('windowResized', function($window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        var ua = $window.navigator.userAgent,
          iPhone = ua.indexOf('iPhone') !== -1 || ua.indexOf('iPod') !== -1,
          iPad = ua.indexOf('iPad') !== -1,
          iOs = iPhone || iPad,
          android = ua.indexOf('Android') !== -1;

        //do something
      }
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic you have there in that directive is solely dependent upon the $window object, I would suggest you add this logic into a service which you could inject into any controllers that would need it.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense, and I have refactored my code accordingly!